# Are floats abstract data types?

Tags: programming-languages, floating-point, abstract-data-types

[image]

Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type

Can we say that float data types (or all primitive data types or only integer) are abstract data types?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you're going by the Wikipedia article you linked, the answer would just be yes: "Formally, an ADT may be defined as a class of objects whose logical behavior is defined by a set of values and a set of operations".

Comment: so, all primitive data types in c language has a proparties and also we can do operations on them,by this and wiki article, we likely to be conclude all primitive data types are also be an abstract data types . is it right ??? @ Fasermaler

Comment: Well, if you go from this definition it's not wrong at least, so you can think about these primitive data types or numerical types as low-level examples of ADTs. However, one could also argue that real numbers are the abstract data type (like the integers) and that C floats and ints are just some implementations allowing you to perform the operations and store (many of) the values defining the ADTs. It depends on context which way of looking at ADTs is most constructive in your situation.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: You simultaneously posted a very similar question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39229292/781723.  We'd ask that you avoid posting the same question on multiple sites -- you shouldn't have the same question open on multiple sites.  If you posted it on the wrong place, delete it on the original site before posting on another Stack Exchange site.  I know someone else suggested you post it here, so it's not your fault (they should have known better)... but now you know for the future.